# How to match an integer after finding a keyword?

Tags: perl, unix

I have a text file content as below:

```
 Starting log...
    Sample at 10000000
    Mode is set to 0
    0007F43: CHANGE DETECTED at  290313 line 0 from 00 to 04
    0007F46: Mismatched at 290316 line 0
    0007F50: Matched occur at 290326 line 1
    0007F53: Mismatched at 290336 line 2
    0007F56: Matched occur at 290346 line 0
    0007F60: Mismatched at 290356 line 2
    0007F63: Matched occur at 290366 line 0
    Saving log....
    DONE!!!
```

I am running simple perl program as below to get the value for the line contains "Mismatched"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Starting perl script\n\n";
open (LOG,"dump.log");

while (<LOG>) {
 next if !/Mismatched/;
 /at\s+"([^"]+)"/;
 print $1,"\n";
}
close(LOG);
print "DONE!!\n";
exit;
```

but what i get the error message as below, may I know what's wrong with my coding? Is it I miss anything related with chomp()?

```
Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 9, <LOG> line 5.
Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 9, <LOG> line 7.
Use of uninitialized value in print at test.pl line 9, <LOG> line 9.
DONE!!
```

And.. is there any suggestion to get the integer (i.e. 290316) after searching the keyword "Mismatched" by using more simple scripting? I just want to get the first value only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got answers that show you the correct way to do this, but nothing yet that explains what you were doing wrong. The problem is in your regex.

```
/at\s+"([^"]+)"/
```

Let's break it down and see what it's trying to match.

- `at` : the string 'at'
- `\s+` : one or more whitespace characters
- `"` : a double quote character
- `([^"]+)` : one or more characters that aren't double quote characters
- `"` : a double quote character

So, effectively, you're looking for 'at' followed by a double quoted string. And you're capturing (into `$1`) the contents of the double quoted string.

But none of your data contains any double quote characters. So there are no double quoted strings. So nothing ever matches and nothing ever gets captured into `$1`. Which is why you get the 'uninitialised value' error when you try to print `$1`.

I'd be interested to hear why you thought you wanted to match double quote characters in a piece of text that doesn't contain any of them.

Answer (score 2):

$1 is getting printed even if it does not have anything. It should be in a condition:

```
print $1,"\n" if (/Mismatched at (\d+)/);
```

To store all values in an array:

```
push @arr,$1 if (/Mismatched at (\d+)/);
```

Comment: what if I want to assign the result in a variable?

Comment: Like this : `$x=$1 if (/Mismatched at (\d+)/);`

Comment: Thanks again.. When I set as variable, it would get the last value because of while loop, so how do I get the first value only?

Comment: You mean you are interested only in the first mismatch value, remaining ones need not even be parsed?

Comment: i want to do something that would store the data in an array, and then when I want to print is the first value, perhaps $array[0]

Answer (score 1):

change regex to:

```
/at\s+(\d+)/;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your script to implement a more modern perl style:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

print "Starting perl script\n\n";
open my $LOG, '<', 'dump.log' or die $!;

while( <$LOG> ) {
  print "$1\n" if /Mismatched at (\d+)/;
}
close $LOG;
print "DONE!!\n";
```